# How to configure ssl on xampp apache

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

Can any one help me in configuring xampp apache server for ssl.
I have tried configuring it as follows in http-ssl:

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
DocumentRoot "project_path"
ServerName domainName
ServerAlias domainName
ErrorLog "errorLog Path
TransferLog "access Log Path"
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "conf/ssl.crt/bundleChain.crt"
</VirtualHost>
```

Errors:

1. When i tried accessing it with DomainName.

   - The site cant be reached.
2. When i tried accessing it with IP and Port.

   - The certificate is issued for domainName and hence ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried this as https://domainName:8443?

Comment: Hi, We have configure DNS from godaddy for our IP and Port, So while testing on browser its just domainName